# HTML returning undefined value (td)

Tags: html, undefined

I am trying to return the values of dynamicTable into a displayed table. i was following a tutorial and have gone wrong somewhere. when i put my data into the table the console logs:

undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined

anyone know where i have gone wrong?

```
<script>
    let sortDirection = false;
    let dynamicTable = [
        { Filename: '7zip', Size: 40, Dateadded: '21/04/2003'},
        { Filename: '7zipTwt', Size: 90, Dateadded: '21/07/2020'}
    ];
    
    window.onload = () => {
        loadTableDt(dynamicTable);
    };
    
    function loadTableDt(dynamicTable) {
        const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableDt');
        let dataHtml = '';
    
        for(let data of dynamicTable) {
            dataHtml += `<tr><td>${dynamicTable.Filename}</td><td>${dynamicTable.Size}</td><td>${dynamicTable.Dateadded}</td></tr>`;
        }
        console.log(dataHtml)
        tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;
    
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form>
        <h1>OceanDrive</h1>
    </form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>File name</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Date added</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableDt"></tbody>
```

Comment: Typo: `let data of dynamicTable` — `data` is the object, `dynamicTable` is the array of objects. `dynamicTable.Filename` needs to be `data.Filename`. **Use the right variable name**.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code I think that I found the cause of the 'undefined' return.
You should change the names of the following elements:

```
dynamicTable.File_Name to dynamicTable.Filename
dynamicTable.SizeF to dynamicTable.Size
dynamicTable.Date_added to dynamicTable.Dateadded
```

It should remove your error and give you the answer that you were looking for.

I hope this will help you, let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'are using wrong properties inside loadTableDt(). For example you use File_name but dynamicTable contains Filename. You have wrong properties for all cases here :)

Comment: Moreover you use `dynamicTable.Filename` but you are inside loop so you should use `data.Filename`

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong property names in the `loadTableDt` function as pointed out in a comment. You can, as an alternative to concatenating the table rows as strings simply call `insertAdjacentHTML` ftom within the loop - it might be more efficient if there are lots of dynamic rows being added. The name of the argument supplied to `loadTableDt` can be completely different to the name of the actual variable - it can help to keep argument names and variables different.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let sortDirection = false;
  let dynamicTable = [{
      Filename: '7zip',
      Size: 40,
      Dateadded: '21/04/2003'
    },
    {
      Filename: '7zipTwt',
      Size: 90,
      Dateadded: '21/07/2020'
    }
  ];


  function loadTableDt(data) {
    const tableBody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    for( let obj of data ) {
      tableBody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<tr>
        <td>${obj.Filename}</td>
        <td>${obj.Size}</td>
        <td>${obj.Dateadded}</td>
      </tr>`);
    }
  }


  loadTableDt(dynamicTable);
};
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>OceanDrive</h1>
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>File name</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Date added</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. this works now :)